# Sorting two associative arrays based on different keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I have the following two associative arrays:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'text' => 'Some text is here',
    'timestamp' => 130458750
)

$arr2 = array(
    'post_id' => 12,
    'content' => 'Some content is here too',
    'created_at' => 1402154823
)
```

I want to sort these two arrays based on `timestamp` and `created_at` keys, i.e. the larger integer is first and lesser second and so on. Is that possible using PHP's built-in functions? If not, how may I approach the problem?

**EDIT**
*The desired result is:* Here, `$arr1`'s timestamp is less and `$arr2`'s timestamp (i.e. created_at) is larger. So, I want to get a combination of `$arr1` and `$arr2` where `$arr2` is first and `$arr1` is second. Something like:

```
$sorted_arr = array($arr2, $arr1);
```

Comment: There's only one timestamp in the array, what are you sorting?

Comment: Are these two arrays actually elements of a 2-dimensional array, and you want to sort that?

Comment: @Barmar, actually there are two timestamps, one is `timestamp`, the other `created_at`. I want to sort the two arrays based on these two values.

Comment: @FerozAkbar, yes, they are associative.

Comment: But the two timestamps are in two different arrays. What do you mean by sorting two arrays?

Comment: Please show what the desired result should be.

Comment: Okay. let me rephrase. Here, `$arr1`'s timestamp is less and `$arr2`'s timestamp (i.e. `created_at`) is larger. So, I want to get a combination of `$arr1` and `$arr2` where `$arr2` is first and `$arr2` is second.

Comment: You ask for `$result = $arr1['timestamp'] > $arr2['timestamp'] ? [$arr1, $arr2] : [$arr2, $arr1]` (assuming that you made mistake saying "`$arr2` is first and `$arr2` is second"). Still I don't think this is what you want. What I think you should be after is `uasort` function.

Comment: @rr- Yes, that's what I want: `$arr1['timestamp'] > $arr2['created_at'] ? [$arr1, $arr2] : [$arr2, $arr1]` but I have too many arrays that I need to sort, not two.

Comment: @rr- yes, that is a mistake $arr1 should be second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining rr-'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24477166/450733), I came up with the following:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'text' => 'Some text is here',
    'timestamp' => 130458750
);

$arr2 = array(
    'post_id' => 12,
    'content' => 'Some content is here too',
    'created_at' => 1402154823
);

$arr3 = array(
    'post_id' => 21,
    'content' => 'Some content is here too',
    'created_at' => 1258475
);
$arr = [];
$arr[] = $arr1;
$arr[] = $arr2;
$arr[] = $arr3;
uasort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = isset($a['timestamp']) ? $a['timestamp'] : $a['created_at'];
    $t2 = isset($b['timestamp']) ? $b['timestamp'] : $b['created_at']; 
    return $t2 - $t1
});
var_dump($arr);
```

It sorts the arrays even when the keys are different.

Comment: You could always use `$t1 = isset($a['timestamp']) ? $a['timestamp'] : $a['created_at']; $t2 = isset($b['timestamp']) ? $b['timestamp'] : $b['created_at']; return $t2 - $t1;` or, better yet, make separate function `function extractTimestamp($array)` in which you could handle all sorts of inputs. (Perhaps make it anonymous and store it in variable to avoid polluting global function namespace.)

Answer (score 1):

First let me say that one of your array contains `timestamp` and second contains `created_at`. I assumed both of them should be `created_at`.

In case you want to "sort" just two entries like you said in the comments, the task is straightforward:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'text' => 'Some text is here',
    'created_at' => 130458750 #corrected from "timestamp"
    );

$arr2 = array(
    'post_id' => 12,
    'content' => 'Some content is here too',
    'created_at' => 1402154823
    );

$posts = $arr2['created_at'] > $arr1['created_at']
    ? [$arr2, $arr1]
    : [$arr1, $arr2];
```

But apparently what you're after is a way to sort the posts if they're in array of unknown length. In that case you should use `uasort` built-in PHP function, which allows to sort by user-defined function and maintains indexes in associative arrays (as opposed to plain `usort`). Example code would then look like this:

```
$posts = [$arr1, $arr2];

uasort($posts, function($a, $b)
{
    return $b['created_at'] - $a['created_at'];
});

var_dump($posts);
```

which outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["post_id"]=>
    int(12)
    ["content"]=>
    string(24) "Some content is here too"
    ["created_at"]=>
    int(1402154823)
  }
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["text"]=>
    string(17) "Some text is here"
    ["created_at"]=>
    int(130458750)
  }
}
```

To get reverse order you may just reverse arguments in custom sort function, i.e. swap `$a` with `$b`.

Comment: The problem is that for the first array `created_at` key doesn't exist. Do I need use array_key_exists inside the comparison function?

Comment: Yes, or better yet, you could make sure your arrays always contain the same keys.

Comment: Thanks! I can't make sure the keys are same because the data is fetched from third party websites.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wrote the function. Please check my answer. Do let me know in case it needs improvement.